# Using cp's interactive option for saving text from stdin

Tags: pipe, cp, stdin

In an interactive shell script I'd like to save the output of a command to a file like in

```
$ echo "Hello, World" > test.txt
```

but prevent test.txt to be overwritten if it already exists.
So I thought it would be a good idea to use **cp** with it's interactive option (**cp -i**) to check if the target file exists.
I tried this:

```
$ echo -n "Hello" | cp -i /dev/stdin test.txt
```

This writes "Hello" to test.txt if test.txt doesn't exist yet, but 
aborts copying if test.txt exists, as cp reads the answer to whether to overwrite or not from just that pipe.

However, this

```
$ cp -i <(echo "World") test.txt
cp: overwrite 'test.txt'? y
'/proc/self/fd/11' -> 'test.txt'
```

works as intended, cp seems to take the subprocess' filedesriptor as source and this is cp'ied to test.txt and I simply don't know why.

Any ideas or explanations or better ways to do it?

Comment: I don't get it. What are you expecting/hoping it will do? Why are you using the interactive option? You say "to prevent overwriting". You then say this fails, because it does not overwrite the existing file "But this fails when test.txt already exists as cp quits with asking and NOT copying". You then say something that dose not make sense about newline characters "as there was a newline in the echoed line anyway".

Comment: Is your question: "Why am I not prompted when I .....?"

Comment: Basically, yes, that's my question. and oh, I was just blind to the fact that piping anything with 'y' to stdin was simply read by cp as an answer to the -i guard. But I still don't get why @uncle-billy 's solution works without a subshell (like mine) but by grouping a list...

Comment: You can edit your question, to make it clearer. And I don't get which part of uncle bill's answer you don't grok.

Answer (score 0):

Use another file descriptor instead of `/dev/stdin`

```
echo Hello | { cp -i /dev/fd/5 test.txt 5<&0 </dev/tty; }
```

Or, still scriptable via yes(1)

```
{ echo Hello | { cp -i /dev/fd/5 test.txt 5<&0 <&4; }; } 4<&0
```

In both variants, the extra `{ ... }` around `cp -i ...` are only needed in zsh, in order to work around its non-standard [multios](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) feature.

This should work in any standard shell and any system which supports `/dev/fd/N` files, except for the Linux + ksh93 combination, which won't work because ksh93 is implementing pipes with Unix sockets, which on Linux cannot be opened via `/dev/fd/N` (not even `echo | cat /dev/stdin` will work).

Your `echo -n "Hello" | cp -i /dev/stdin test.txt` will actually clobber the file if instead of `"Hello"` you put `"You suck!"` there. That's one of the reasons why you shouldn't rely on `cp -i`.

Comment: Thanks, but the former doesn't work at all for me, even if test.txt doesn't exist, it seems to be touched, but left empty.

Comment: Maybe your cp is an alias. The fact that it shows the files being copied (as cp -v) suggests as much.

Comment: Also, where did you get the idea that it needs a newline: it doesn't. `printf y | cp -vi src dst` will clobber `dst`, without any newline after `y`.

Comment: It acutally is, but echo Hello | /bin/cp -i /dev/fd/5 test.txt 5<&0 </dev/tty results in the same empty file. And I don't get why replacing the echo'ed text would clobber the file? Isn't cp -i meant to prevent just that?

Comment: It does not, on my system. What system are you using? `cp -i` reads a line from stdin (it doesn't have to be a complete line, terminated by `\n`, it may be all the text up to EOF), and if it starts by `y` or `Y` goes on and clobbers the file.

Comment: Aboutthe newline: echo "elephant" | /bin/cp -i /dev/stdin test.txt              
results in /bin/cp: overwrite 'test.txt'? %  as if any answer but 'y' was given, eg. a simple hit of enter.

Comment: You can simulate that from the command line too: `touch src dst; cp -i src dst` and press Control-D twice. wrt your "elephant" example: yes, but will only truncate the file (to 0 size) if "**y**elephant" was used instead of "elephant".

Comment: That's a zsh 5.1 on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: @zot I have added more compat info about zsh and ksh93. See the [recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578365/325065) where I've stolen the zsh doc link from.

Answer (score 0):

Shells such as `bash` can already protect against overwriting files with a redirect

```
set -o noclobber
echo hello >world
echo hello >world
-bash: world: cannot overwrite existing file
```

If you want to be able to ask the user before overwriting, I would use something like this instead of the `noclobber` setting

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define function sureYN  [<prompt>]  <target>
sureYN() {
    local prompt="$1" target="$2" yn='y'
    [[ -z "$target" ]] && { target="$prompt"; prompt="Overwrite $target"; }

    [[ -f "$target" && -t 0 ]] && read -p "$prompt (y/n)? " yn >&2
    [[ "$yn" =~ ^[Yy] ]]
}

sureYN /tmp/first && cp -fp /etc/hosts /tmp/first
sureYN "Can I replace /tmp/second" /tmp/second && echo this is the second >/tmp/second
```

Comment: Thx, that is most useful but later I need to let the user decide whether to overwrite or not. So uncle billy's  approach might be more suitable once I understand that maze of curly brackets...

Comment: If it's a script what's wrong with `yn=y; [[ -f "$target" ]] && read -p "Are you sure? " yn; [[ "$yn" == y ]] && echo foo >"$target"` or whatever?

Comment: technically nothing except for my wish to reuse existing tools (if it's possible) and for that I would have to use a named pipe if the "echo foo" part becomes a real piped stream, or am I missing something?

Comment: @zot there you go: a reusable function for your script