# Why is stdout from the first command in this pipe not being processed?

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe

I'm trying to write a command that can simultaneously (i) read from stdin and (ii) read from a pipe.  This basic concept works in `zsh`, but not in `bash`.  The following session illustrates the difference in behavior for the two shells:

```bsh
$ echo bar > bar
$ zsh -f
zsh-5.8$ echo foo | cat < bar
foo
bar
zsh-5.8$ exit
$ bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.0$ echo foo | cat < bar
bar
```

I can see that the above commands give `cat` two sources of stdin (the pipe and the redirect), so perhaps it's ambiguous how that should be handled.  `zsh` seems to concatenate the two input streams, with the piped input consistently coming first.  `bash` seems to simply drop the piped input.

My questions are:

1. Why do the two shells behave differently?
2. Is there any way to force `bash` to behave like `zsh`?

Comment: 1. Because they're different shells and the operation (AFAIK) has no POSIX definition. 2. No.

Comment: @roaima I don't think your claim 1. is correct. Do you have any reference? I think that in a POSIX shell, the `cat` should only read from `bar` in `echo | cat < bar`, and the `MULTIOS` feature in zsh makes it not standard compliant.

Comment: @UncleBilly I couldn't find a POSIX statement. That doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: @roaima Just like nobody knows that there isn't a [teapot orbiting the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance), right? It's you who made the assertion that a redirection in a pipeline is undefined behaviour in POSIX, you should prove it.

Comment: @UncleBilly I've made no assertion that the pipeline is undefined behaviour in POSIX. I said (1) that _as far as I knew_ there was no POSIX definition for reading _stdin_ from two different sources, (2) that I couldn't find a POSIX statement (either way). If I had a definitive statement I would have written a proper answer citing the source.

Comment: @roaima It's specified in Section 2.9.2 of the POSIX Shell Command Language https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02 **The standard input, standard output, or both of a command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline before any redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the command**

Comment: This means that it first assigns stdin to the pipe, then it redirects it to the file. It doesn't combine them.

Comment: @Barmar that's brilliant - thank you for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have noticed, the [`MULTIOS` shell option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) in `zsh` is what makes this possible.  There is no similar built in facility in the `bash` shell.

In `bash`, you would get the same behavior (for this particular example; see [Uncle Billy's comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578365/why-is-stdout-from-the-first-command-in-this-pipe-not-being-processed/578397?noredirect=1#comment1076352_578397)) from

```
echo foo | { cat; cat bar; }
```

or

```
echo foo | cat - bar
```

Both of these right hand sides first read their standard inputs before reading `bar`.

Comment: The link from your answer explicitly mentions that Multios behaves differently from cat: "each file is opened immediately, not at the point where it is about to be read: this behaviour differs from cat". And indeed, even such simple examples as those from you answer will behave differently if `bar` is a fifo or an unreadable file.

Answer (score 4):

I spent some more time looking at this, and I found that the behavior of `zsh` is due to the [`MULTIOS` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios), which is enabled by default.  `bash` doesn't seem to have a comparable option, so this behavior is specific to `zsh`.